# How to wrap long lines in a text using Regular Expressions when you also need to indent the wrapped lines?

Tags: python, ruby, regex, word-wrap

How can one change the following text

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

to

```
The quick brown fox +
    jumps over the +
    lazy dog.
```

using regex?

#### UPDATE1

A solution for Ruby is still missing... A simple one I came to so far is

```
def textwrap text, width, indent="\n"
  return text.split("\n").collect do |line|
    line.scan( /(.{1,#{width}})(\s+|$)/ ).collect{|a|a[0]}.join  indent
  end.join("\n")
end
puts textwrap 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.', width=19, indent=" + \n    "
# >> The quick brown fox + 
# >>     jumps over the lazy + 
# >>     dog.
```

Comment: Perl with the /x modifier? ;)

Answer (score 5):

Maybe use [textwrap](http://docs.python.org/library/textwrap.html#module-textwrap) instead of regex:

```
import textwrap

text='The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'

print(' + \n'.join(
    textwrap.wrap(text, initial_indent='', subsequent_indent=' '*4, width=20)))
```

yields:

```
The quick brown fox + 
    jumps over the + 
    lazy dog.
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I also need it for Ruby for which I cannot find such function. It seems that I need to write it myself...