# wrapping long lines *within* a Sheets cell

Tags: regex, google-sheets

So I've got some long lines in a cell, and I'd like to force-wrap the lines, before the last space before the 180th character.

i.e. of the string [170-190] is:

> test foo bar baz band

Since the 180th character is the `a` in `bar`, I'd like it to become

> test foo\n bar baz band

Similar to the requirement in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451308/how-to-wrap-long-lines-in-a-text-using-regular-expressions-when-you-also-need-to/3451365), but using Sheets' built-in functions rather than Python/Ruby.

### Dead-ends so far

#### String methods

Searching online, I [came across this post](https://trumpexcel.com/find-characters-last-position/), and derived this to find the last space before 180, and keep only what's to the `left()`:

`=left(B5,FIND("",SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(B5,180)," ","",LEN(LEFT(B5,180))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(B5,180)," ",""))),1)-1)`

I imagine to get this to work multiple times per line would require an exponential complexity explosion or a custom function.

#### REGEXREPLACE

I'm looking into `regexreplace`, since I'd like this replacement to occur as many times as needed (a single line could need to wrap 2+ times).

Playing with regex101.com, I can find the 180th non-newline with `^\n{180}`, but I've not been able to find anything that explains how one might capture the line's characters only up to the preceding space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(B5,"(.{180}) ",CONCAT("$1",char(10)))
```

It counts 180 characters (captured with group 1) followed by a space and it replace it with the content of group 1 concatenated with a newline (`char(10)`).

**EDIT**: If you need to match strictly less than 180 characters, then you can use:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(B5,"(\b[^\n]{0,180}) ",CONCAT("$1",char(10)))
```

**EDIT:** tightening the range to not add newlines after short lines

```
=REGEXREPLACE(B5,"(\b[^\n]{150,177}) ",CONCAT("$1",char(10)))
```

Comment: it really needs to be _less than_ 180 chars in total, though - and no way to be sure how long individual words will be either.

Comment: Very nice! Slight tweak: `"(\b[^\n]{0,180}) "` so that each _native_ newline resets the 180-counter. Looking into some wierdness (some shorter lines still getting wrapped), but I think this will be the one!

Comment: Ok so one last hick - this will also match and wrap lines that have [significantly] less than 180 chars - I raised the lower limit to compensate.  I also lowered the upper limit due to some weird corner-cases I couldn't explain: `(\b[^\n]{150,177}) `